# mysql cursor not fetching data from select query inside stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, cursor

I have written the following procedure but the the cursor is not displaying or inserting any data. I have ran the select query separately and it returns data properly.

I tried checking other solutions on stack overflow and dba stack exchange but the solutions are not fixing the issue.

The most close answer found was on dba exchange [This](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15607/why-is-this-mysql-proc-using-cursors-failing-to-retrieve-results?newreg=47ed359e8b214fac827d1902122d888d)

As advise in the answers in the above mentioned links I renamed all the variables with _ in varibalename but still it cursor doesn't display or insert data

Any help would be appriciated.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE getUniquePartnerIds()
BEGIN

DECLARE temp_partnerId INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE is_finished INTEGER DEFAULT 0;

DECLARE cursor_Partnerid CURSOR FOR 
SELECT DISTINCT partnerId FROM multiplepartners WHERE partnerId NOT IN (SELECT partnerId FROM partner_language);

DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET is_finished = 1;
        
OPEN cursor_Partnerid;
        
get_PartnerId: LOOP
FETCH cursor_Partnerid INTO temp_partnerId;
-- SELECT temp_partnerId;
IF is_finished = 1 THEN LEAVE get_PartnerId;
END IF;     
        
-- INSERT INTO `partner_language`(`partnerid`)
-- VALUES (temp_partnerId);     
END LOOP get_PartnerId;
CLOSE cursor_Partnerid;
    
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: 'I renamed all the variables with _ in' - did you , I don't see any such variables n the code. BTW distinct is not a function (partnerId) should not be bracketed.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your issue, https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gsitBkPviSKDrxrrSWkCVS/0 voting to close as not reproducible.

Comment: @P.Salmon I meant the variable names temp_partnerId, is_finished were earlier only partnerId, finished.
I added _ in a prefix to them.

I have removed the round bracket for distinct, the select query works fine with or without () with distinct keyword.

but when used with cursor it is not fetching data.